# Does the WebClient Class Have a Complement Class for the .DownloadFile() and .UploadFile() Operations?

Tags: c#, .net, communication

The `System.Net.WebClient class` has 2 useful methods for file transfer:
`WebClient.DownloadFile()` and `WebClient.UploadFile()`.

Both these methods expect a Web Server on the other side, like IIS, Apache, etc,
from which the file will be downloaded from or uploaded to..

Does the .NET Framework have a complement class to the `Webclient class`, that can act as "the other side" for the `.DownloadFile()` and `.UploadFile()` operations,
without installing a full blown web server?

I can write such class, implementing the HTTP protocol for these 2 operations,
but before I do that, If such a complementing class exists, I would of course prefer to use it and not reinvent the wheel..

Comment: You can create a [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) project which will act as the receiving side which hosts the files. Or if you want something more raw, you can simply implement the [`IHttpHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler(v=vs.110).aspx) interface

Comment: Hi Yuval. The WebAPI is a part of ASP.NET, and to run ASP.NET you will then need a web server.. You will not be able to create a simple WinForms/Console project, use some class, and run it on any computer..

Comment: That's incorrect. You can use [WebAPI self-host](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api), and start it from a console app.